# CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length while trying to download cudnn using conda

Tags: python, anaconda

This is the error I'm having in the anaconda prompt, after executing the command: `conda install cudnn==7.6.5`
Error:

```
CondaError: Downloaded bytes did not match Content-Length
  url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/cudnn-7.6.5-cuda10.1_0.conda
  target_path: C:\Users\User\anaconda3\pkgs\cudnn-7.6.5-cuda10.1_0.conda
  Content-Length: 187807360
  downloaded bytes: 165935561
```

Note that I am not installing it in a new environment but in the base.
I would appreciate any help!!

Comment: first try removing the `cudnn` package before reinstalling it

Comment: @Jenny - Did you fnd a fix for it, if yes, please update here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. using `curl` download package
2. `conda install --offline your_download_package`

Answer (score 0):

Try go to target_path and uninstall cudnn or just install cudnn in target_path.
It works for me when I install cudatoolkit.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have an error when you try to download the package.  When you try to download it again sometimes you will face this and you can try to remove the file you have downloaded before, for example on here *C:\Users\User\anaconda3\pkgs\cudnn-7.6.5-cuda10.1_0.conda* ,
So try this in your anaconda prompt:

1. `rm C:\Users\User\anaconda3\pkgs\cudnn-7.6.5-cuda10.1_0.conda`
2. try install again your package